# How to display certain category using WordPress api

Tags: wordpress, flutter, api, dart, wordpress-rest-api

I'm developing a mobile app using WordPress API and I'm trying to display only certain categories instead of all the categories.

Currently I'm doing it like this and it showing all the categories but just wondering how can I filter and only show category with ID 4 and 5?

````
//My API call
   void getCategories() async {
      try {
        var response = await Network().simpleGet("/categories?parent=0");

        var body = json.decode(response.body);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          categories.state = body;
          var box = await Hive.openBox('appBox');
          box.put('categories', json.encode(body));
        } else {}
        loadingCategories.value = false;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }


//This is how I'm displaying
Row(
                                        children: categories.state
                                            .map((category) => Container(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 10),
                                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      right: 10),
                                                  child: InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                                        context,
                                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                                CategoryDetail(
                                                                    category:
                                                                        category))),
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      category['name'],
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: color.state ==
                                                                  'dark'
                                                              ? Color(
                                                                  0xFFA19E9C)
                                                              : primaryText),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ))
                                            .toList(),
                                      ),
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of

```
categories.state.map((category)
```

You do something like

```
categories.state.where((category) => category == xx).map((category)
```

Just add some filtering logic there ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I try adding some Id value and it's not showing me anything anymore. Could you please help me with this agian?